# Go сервер Https

Tags: golang

Пытаюсь запустить приложение, написанное на Go, с использованием самоподписанного SSL сертификата. Пример:

```
func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.Handle("/", httpHandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        if r.URL.Path != "/" {
            http.Error(w, "404", http.StatusNotFound)
            return
        }

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte("Hello Https"))
    }))

    http.Handle("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "cert.pem", "cert.key", mux))
}
```

Какие действия предпринимались:

1. Создание сертификата через гошный generate_cert.go, но получаю ошибку: TLS handhsake EOF
2. Пробовал с помощью встроенного в Linux openssl создать сертификат, результат тот же

Как генерирую сертификат:
go run generate_cert.go --host="127.0.0.1" (в случае со встроенной утилитой)
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 (в случае со встроенным в linux openssl)

UPD: Браузер считает сертификат (Acme Co) не подлинным / ненадёжным

Comment: Https обычно слушает порт 443, а не 80

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо за подсказку, обновил код. Пробовал менять на 443 и открывал порт через ufw (у меня Ubuntu сервер), но ничего не поменялось.